# Raw query must include the primary key

Tags: django, django-models

I got a raw SQL statement in my `views.py`

```
Message.objects.raw('''
        SELECT s1.ID, s1.CHARACTER_ID, MAX(s1.MESSAGE) MESSAGE, MAX(s1.c) occurrences
        FROM
           (SELECT ID, CHARACTER_ID, MESSAGE, COUNT(*) c
            FROM tbl_message WHERE ts > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL %s DAY) GROUP BY CHARACTER_ID,MESSAGE) s1
        LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT ID, CHARACTER_ID, MESSAGE, COUNT(*) c
            FROM tbl_message WHERE ts > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL %s DAY) GROUP BY CHARACTER_ID,MESSAGE) s2
          ON s1.CHARACTER_ID=s2.CHARACTER_ID
         AND s1.c < s2.c
        WHERE s2.c IS NULL
        GROUP BY CHARACTER_ID
        ORDER BY occurrences DESC''', [days, days])
```

The result of this SQL statement (tested on database directly) is:

```
ID  | CHARACTER_ID | MESSAGE | OCCURENCES
----+--------------+---------+--------------
148 | 10           | test    | 133
```

But all I got is a `InvalidQuery` Exception with the information `Raw query must include the primary key`

Then I double checked the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#deferring-model-fields) and read:

> There is only one field that you can’t leave out - the primary key
>   field....An InvalidQuery exception will be raised if you forget to include the primary key.

As you can see I got the requested primary key added in my statement. What's wrong?

```
class Message(models.Model):
    character = models.ForeignKey('Character')
    message = models.TextField()
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location')
    ts = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        pass

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s: %s...' % (self.character, self.message[0:20])
```

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Comment: I did a workaround with a view...but if you have a solution, feel free to post it.

Comment: Can you post your `Message` model?

Comment: What was the workaround? I am in your exact situation. Case sensitivity does not solve it for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I reproduced the same problem using Python 2.7.5, Django 1.5.1 and Mysql 5.5.

I've saved the result of the `raw` call to the `results` variable, so I can check what columns it contains:

```
>>> results.columns
['ID', 'CHARACTER_ID', 'MESSAGE', 'occurrences']
```

`ID` is in uppercase, so in your query I changed `s1.ID` to `s1.id` and it works:

```
>>> results = Message.objects.raw('''
...         SELECT s1.id, s1.CHARACTER_ID, MAX(s1.MESSAGE) MESSAGE, MAX(s1.c) occurrences
...         FROM
...            (SELECT ID, CHARACTER_ID, MESSAGE, COUNT(*) c
...             FROM tbl_message WHERE ts > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL %s DAY) GROUP BY CHARACTER_ID,MESSAGE) s1
...         LEFT JOIN
...            (SELECT ID, CHARACTER_ID, MESSAGE, COUNT(*) c
...             FROM tbl_message WHERE ts > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL %s DAY) GROUP BY CHARACTER_ID,MESSAGE) s2
...           ON s1.CHARACTER_ID=s2.CHARACTER_ID
...          AND s1.c < s2.c
...         WHERE s2.c IS NULL
...         GROUP BY CHARACTER_ID
...         ORDER BY occurrences DESC''', [days, days])
>>> results.columns
['id', 'CHARACTER_ID', 'MESSAGE', 'occurrences']
>>> results[0]
<Message_Deferred_character_id_location_id_message_ts: Character object: hello...>
```

Answer (score 32):

Include 1 as id to your query

```
Message.objects.raw('''
        SELECT 1 as id , s1.ID, s1.CHARACTER_ID, MAX(s1.MESSAGE) MESSAGE, MAX(s1.c) occurrences
        FROM
           (SELECT ID, CHARACTER_ID, MESSAGE, COUNT(*) c
            FROM tbl_message WHERE ts > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL %s DAY) GROUP BY CHARACTER_ID,MESSAGE) s1
        LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT ID, CHARACTER_ID, MESSAGE, COUNT(*) c
            FROM tbl_message WHERE ts > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL %s DAY) GROUP BY CHARACTER_ID,MESSAGE) s2
          ON s1.CHARACTER_ID=s2.CHARACTER_ID
         AND s1.c < s2.c
        WHERE s2.c IS NULL
        GROUP BY CHARACTER_ID
        ORDER BY occurrences DESC''', [days, days])
```

Comment: This is useful since it also prevents problems when you group by and want to ignore the id field.

Answer (score 5):

Make Sure the primary key is part of the select statement.

Example:

This will not work:

```
`Model.objects.raw("Select Min(id), rider_id from Table_Name group by rider_id")`
```

But this will work:

```
`Model.objects.raw("Select id, Min(id), rider_id from Table_Name group by rider_id")`
```

Answer (score 3):

For those also stuck with this problem, perhaps like me, wondering why Django needs a `pk`, when you don’t have a `pk` for the query (eg you want multiple rows) – Django just needs an `id` field returned, the `pk` does not need to be part of a `where` clause. ie:

`select * from table where foo = 'bar';`

or

`select id, description from table where foo = 'bar';`

Both of these work, if there is a field `id` in the table. But this throws the error described by Thomas Schwärzl, because no `id` field is returned:

`select description from table where foo = 'bar';`

Comment: Thanks for the trick. I have rename my field with `SELECT my_field as id...` and it works !