# Django - Raw query must include the primary key

Tags: python, sql, django

There is a similar question here - [Raw query must include the primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347445/raw-query-must-include-the-primary-key)

However I'm running off of a legacy DB and therefore can't figure out what the issue is with the Primary Key.

This is my RAW query -

```
trg = Trgjob.objects.db_manager('AdmiralDEV').raw("""
    SELECT jobdep_id, jm.jobmst_id, jobdep_type, (jm1.jobmst_prntname + '\' + jm1.jobmst_name) AS jobdep_jobmst,
    jobdep_operator, jobdep_status, jobdep_joblogic, jobdep_ingroup, jobdep_dateoffset, jobdep_instoffset,
    jobdep_canignore, jobdep_filename, jobdep_filetype, jobdep_fileextent, nodmst_id, varmst_id, jobdep_value
    FROM Jobdep jd
    INNER JOIN Jobmst jm ON jd.jobmst_id = jm.jobmst_id
    INNER JOIN Jobmst jm1 ON jd.jobdep_jobmst = jm1.jobmst_id
    WHERE jm.jobmst_id = 9878""")
```

On the DB works fine, but in django I get the following failure -

Raw query must include the primary key

The primary key on this model is "jobdep_id" as seen in the models.py here -

```
class Jobdep(models.Model):
    jobdep_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to write query as:

```
"SELECT jobdep_id AS id ..."
```

maybe it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Manager.raw() it's required to provide the id. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries)

> There is only one field that you can’t leave out - the primary key
>   field. Django uses the primary key to identify model instances, so it
>   must always be included in a raw query. An InvalidQuery exception will
>   be raised if you forget to include the primary key.

But you can execute custom SQL directly to avoid this. See more on Django documentation 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Answer (score 2):

The issue was indeed my models.py I had to update it as follows -

```
class Jobdep(models.Model):
    jobdep_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='jobdep_id', primary_key=True)
```